# (-215, Assertion failed) error when attempting to create a mask for an image, but only occurs when i uncomment a line

Tags: python, opencv

[image: reference image]

I am attempting to take the image above and crop the image down to just the pvc pipe so that I can later on determine the differences between this reference image and another image. (I will possibly ask another question later on if any issues arise when I try to do that) I am currently attempting to find the any of the pink or white pvc in the image, and I have successfully done that utilizing numpy to split the bgr array of the image. Here is my code so far.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("CoralImgs/Original.png")

c = image.copy()

c = cv2.resize(c, (480, 380), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

for y in range(480):
    for x in range(720):
        b, g, r = image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 2] # for BGR image


for y in range(len(r)):
    for x in range(len(r[y])):
        if r[y][x] < 170:
            r[y][x] = 0

# mask_b = cv2.bitwise_and(c, c, mask=r)

cv2.imshow("r", r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However when I uncomment the line above `mask_b = cv2.bitwise_and(c, c, mask=r)` I get the following error, I also understand that this error is usually the case of the source image being empty, but it only occurs when I uncomment that line.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:230: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

So what I am asking here is for help understanding why the error is occuring and hopefully find a fix for it so that I do not have this problem again.

Thank you!!!!

-- as a last second thought I wanted to add what the code returns when the line in question is commented out.
[image: mask image that I want to apply]

Comment: The shapes of `c` and `r` are different - `c` is resized version of the image, `r` is the red plane from the original, unresized image. | Just out of curiosity, why do you assign the same thing to `b`, `g` and `r` 345600 times? Wouldn't once be enough?

Comment: I didn't assign the same thing to b,g,r. I thought this was the way to split the bgr values into 3 seperate arrays so that I can manipulate each pixel value of the image. Is this the incorrect way of doing this? And I also see what you mean by the size differences, I didn't realize that Thank you

Comment: I mean this: `b, g, r = image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 2]` -- that splits the whole `image` into the 3 colour planes. You only need to call that once, not inside the two nested `for` loops. Notice that neither `x`, nor `y` are used anywhere in that expression, so each of the many iterations produces exactly the same result over and over and over...

Comment: I understand now, I'm sorry this method of splitting the image is new to me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So as Dan Mašek (I do not know how to @ people, I need to figure that out) said in the comments. The reason I was getting that error was due to my images being of two sizes and after modifying the code above a little bit here was the result.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("CoralImgs/Original.png")

c = image.copy()

c = cv2.resize(c, (480, 380), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

b, g, r = c[:, :, 0], c[:, :, 1], c[:, :, 2] # for BGR image


for y in range(len(r)):
    for x in range(len(r[y])):
        if r[y][x] < 170:
            r[y][x] = 0

mask_b = cv2.bitwise_and(c, c, mask=r)

cv2.imshow("r", r)
cv2.imshow("mask_b", mask_b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: new images]

[Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) Thanks Again!

Comment: Good. Next step is to get rid of that second set of nested loops. You're again making several hundred thousand iterations, and due to the interpreter overhead, this will take a long time as is. Notice that you're performing the same operation to every pixel -- this is a good candidate for vectorization. You could use numpy, but since you tagged the question as OpenCV, this is a good example of thresholding. Read the documentation of `cv2.threshold` and the associated tutorial.